# Is there a way to put arrows at the end of a line without having to draw them?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to make some lines that end with an arrow at the end of a semicircle using the Tikz package and for that I'm currently using this disgusting looking code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[black, thick](-2,0)arc(180:360:2);
\foreach \lab[count=\n,evaluate=\n as \angle using ((\n+1)*-22.5)+45] 
    in {+4,+3,+2,+1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4}
        {\draw[black, thick](\angle:2cm)--(\angle:2.3cm)node [anchor=\angle-180]{$\lab$};}
\draw[black, thick](2,0)--(2,0.5);
\draw[black, thick](2,0.5)--(1.7,0.2);
\draw[black, thick](2,0.5)--(2.3,0.2);
\draw[black, thick](-2,0)--(-2,0.5);
\draw[black, thick](-2,0.5)--(-1.7,0.2);
\draw[black, thick](-2,0.5)--(-2.3,0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This creates the following figure:

[image]

I'll need to make these quite often and this code is not only bad to write at times but the figure doesn't look good also, is there another way I can rewrite this? Thanks in advance

Comment: "the figure doesn't look good also" - "doesn't look good" is subjective, what would you consider an _improvement_? - To give answerers something to strive for?

Comment: @MrWhite I'm sorry, I didn't pay attention to that, what I mean is that the arrows look too big compared to the rest of the semi circle; anyways, the question was already answered but thanks for pointing that out, will surely help in future questions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I guess most TikZ tutorials will tell you, you add arrow tips to the ends of the path with `<->` added to the path option, e.g. `\draw [<->] (0,0) -- (1,1);`. The default arrow tips are a bit small, but with the arrow tips from the `arrows.meta` library you can customize the size of the tips. That library is documented in section 16.5 of the current TikZ manual.

So you can for example do as in the code below. Here I defined a new arrow tip called `bigT`, and used `bigT-bigT` in the path options. Note also I extended the arc with straight lines.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  bigT/.tip={Stealth[width=4mm,length=4mm]}
]
\draw[black, thick, bigT-bigT]  (-2,0.5) -- (-2,0) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=2] -- +(0,0.5);
\foreach \lab[count=\n,evaluate=\n as \angle using ((\n+1)*-22.5)+45] 
    in {+4,+3,+2,+1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4}
        {\draw[black, thick](\angle:2cm)--(\angle:2.3cm)node [anchor=\angle-180]{$\lab$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Addendum:

If you're making many such diagrams, it would make more sense to put the definition of the arrow tip in the preamble. You could also make a `style` for the "axis" line.

Below I also define a function for the radius, to parameterize the drawing, and show a slightly different approach to the loop. Not saying this is better than yours, consider it as inspiration rather.

Oh, and the `Straight Barb` arrow tip is similar to your original, but see the documentation for a complete list available tips.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  % define a new arrow tip style
  bigT/.tip={Straight Barb[width=4mm,length=3mm]},
  % make a style for the "axis"
  curveaxis/.style={thick, bigT-bigT},
  % a new function for the radius
  declare function={R=2;}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% use the style defined above and the radius function
\draw[curveaxis]  (-R,R/4) -- (-R,0)
                                arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=R] -- 
                                +(0,R/4);

\foreach \lab [evaluate={\angle={180+(\lab+4)*22.5}}]
    in {-4,...,4}
        {\draw[thick] (\angle:R)-- ++(\angle:R/10) node[anchor=\angle-180]{\ifnum\lab=0$0$\else\pgfmathprintnumber[showpos]{\lab}\fi};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you man, it did work but is there a way of not filling the arrows in black? Also, I knew about adding arrows with <-> but when I use it I get this error:! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.93 \draw(0,0)<
                ->(1,0);

Comment: @TheWonkaBro Try the `Straight Barb` tip, as in the code I just added to my answer. You're using `<->` in the wrong place. It's `\draw [<->] (0,0) -- (1,1);`, not `\draw (0,0) <-> (1,1);`

Comment: Thank you man! You helped me solve two big problems!